How to solve Bitbucket pipeline error : vendor/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory
For my Laravel application, I have created a bitbucket-pipeline :
image: php:8.0
pipelines:
  branches:
    stage:
      - step:
          name: Install Dependencies
          caches:
            - composer
            - node
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev
            - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
            - docker-php-ext-install gd
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
            - mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
            - composer install --no-scripts
            - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
            - apt-get install -y nodejs
            - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
      - step:
          name: Run Tests
          script:
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
      - step:
          name: Build Assets
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm run prod
      - step:
          name: Migrate Database
          script:
            - php artisan migrate --force
            - php artisan key:generate
            - php artisan jwt:secret
          services:
            - mysql

definitions:
  services:
      mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7

caches:
  composer: ~/.composer/cache
  node: ~/.npm


So far so good, but when I run this, I get the error:
bash: vendor/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory

I checked that the folder exist and everything is fine, but i still get the error.
can someone help me out?

Please reduce your code to a [mre], right now it features a lot of steps that aren't relevant to your question and make it hard to focus on the problem

should not the command be php vendor/bin/phpunit?

Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/77184175/11715259

Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/74815052/11715259

Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/74220389/11715259

Try use absolute path.
/var/www/your-project/vendor/bin/phpunit

I think that step "Run Tests" must be after "Migrate Database".

depends on how the test are run. some use temporary file database to test code, not the actual database used by the app.

Exercise for the reader: link all questions regarding this recurring confusion.

Each pipeline steps happens in a pristine docker container. Thus, the installation instructions of any tooling must be repeated in every and each step using that tooling! You must not rely on caches making software available, caches are solely meant to speed-up the install instructions, but aren't guaranteed to be present (e.g. think about re-running a step after a cache has been cleared or expired).
From https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/#Best-practices

Remember that caches are temporary, so your builds should be configured to work whether or not the cache is present.

definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7

caches:
  composer: ~/.composer/cache
  node: ~/.npm

pipelines:
  branches:
    stage:
      - step:
          name: Run Tests
          image: composer:2
          caches: [composer]
          script:
            - composer install --no-scripts
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
      - step:
          image: node:18
          name: Build Assets
          caches: [node]
          script:
            - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
            - npm run prod
      - step:
          name: Migrate Database
          image: composer:2
          caches: [composer]
          script:
            - composer install --no-scripts  # Yes, again
            - php artisan migrate --force
            - php artisan key:generate
            - php artisan jwt:secret
          services:
            - mysql



You can also create a custom cache in bitbucket-pipelines.yaml for the vendor folder and re-use that in follow-up steps, so you don't have to do "composer install" all over again. It works in my case, EXCEPT the vendor/bin folder is missing. Not sure why...

@acme you should NEVER skip the composer install instruction, because of the details I already explained. It can work most of the times, but only accidentally. Caching the vendor folder is nonsense (and an actual burden regarding pipeline performance) unless you can guarantee its presence speeds up the mandatory composer install instruction.

Ah, I see - you mean because theoretically it could happen that the cache gets invalidated between the first and the last step in your example. But what do you mean by caching the vendor folder affects the pipeline performance in a negative way?

And also, you may need to re-run the second step after a time has passed, which increases the chances for the cache having been expired, invalidated or polluted. Caching a folder means (1) creating a .tar.gz (2) uploading it to a remote storage (3) download it in every future step and (4) unpack it in every future step. Caching imposes a non-negligible workload which should be compared to time saving measurements in the script.

One thing to come around using composer install in every step might be to do that in the initial one and then use vendor/**  as artifacts. Depends of course also a bit if that makes any difference in terms of speed.
